# Redirect:/ После авторизации Spring java

Tags: java, веб-программирование, xml, spring, авторизация

На сайте система авторизации. Spring security. Запускаю сервер, ввожу логин и пароль и мне необходимо перейти на определенную страницу: "**localhost:8080/forum/0**" А меня перекидывает на на адрес: '**localhost:8080**';

В ***config-security.xml*** я указал, что необходимо переходить по определенному адресу:

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/forum" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
   <!--При запуске открывается /login потом должно /forum/0-->
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/forum/0" authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
                username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"/>

    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"/>
</http>
```

И вот что, первый раз отправляю данные логина и пароля на сервер, переходит по адресу: '**localhost:8080**', ошибка 404, нажимаю **назад**, снова отправляю данные на сервер и тогда уже как надо переходит по адресу "**localhost:8080/forum/0**". Почему? Как сделать, что-бы сразу переходил по нужному адресу?

**@Controller**

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(Model model, String error, String logout) {
   //реализация
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = {"/forum/{id}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String forum(Model model, @PathVariable("id") int id) {
    //реализация
    return "forum";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
<form-login login-page="/login"
        default-target-url="/forum/0"
        always-use-default-target="true"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password"/>
```

Или 2й вариант - реализовать свой `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`, в котором будет редирект на нужную страницу - (пример)[http://www.baeldung.com/spring_redirect_after_login]

Comment: always-use-default-target="true" - это именно то, что нужно